# How to get Unique Array whose elemets are Objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Below is an examplle of an array I have

```
var mm =  [
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0245.JPG","text":"IMG_0245.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0246.JPG","text":"IMG_0246.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0247.JPG","text":"IMG_0247.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0248.JPG","text":"IMG_0248.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0249.JPG","text":"IMG_0249.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0250.JPG","text":"IMG_0250.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"IMG_0251.JPG","text":"IMG_0251.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"jingling.rar","text":"jingling.rar","parent":"Junk"},
    {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
    {"id":"pics.rar","text":"pics.rar","parent":"Junk"}
];
```

If you notice, the first and third objects in the array are same and so on. I've looked up for built in functions but I couldnt find any. IS there any simple built in. simple function to do this in jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Do you have the same ID to all objects or it was just a typo?

Comment: Yes, the ID of objects that are similar have to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var o = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(o.hasOwnProperty(JSON.stringify(this[i]))) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      o[JSON.stringify(this[i])] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

This will return you an array with unique values only. I don't think there is any built-in function for it.

Comment: I was looking for a jQuery or javascript answer.But thanks anyway!

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep: This is plain JavaScript. To invoke: `var cleanedArray = mm.getUnique();` `cleanedArray` will contain the array without doubles.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/y9hb60qu/ Doesn't seem to work? I just get the first array.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep  I've examined this answer and corrected some of the problems: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hb60qu/3/

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work. The function returns an array with only one element - the first one of the original array (unless you have other elements that are primitives). Here is why: object properties' names can only be strings (at least as of ECMAScript 5.1). You cannot have an object act as a key for a property, it will be converted to `[object Object]`. This way, the first `if` condition will fail, since there are no properties in the object yet, but each subsequent iteration will end up checking whether the object has the property called `[object Object]` and continue the loop.

Comment: My internet is slow right now.Will check it in a while.Thank you.

Comment: @Mykybo that specific page doesnt seem to load.All other fiddles are fine :( Can you post it on pastebin so that I can have a look?

Comment: @Sai Krishna Deep I have editted the answer, works now for your case as well. For some reason fiddle is not working for me atm.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID of the objects is always the same you can do this:

```js
var mm =  [  {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0245.JPG","text":"IMG_0245.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0246.JPG","text":"IMG_0246.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0247.JPG","text":"IMG_0247.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0248.JPG","text":"IMG_0248.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0249.JPG","text":"IMG_0249.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0250.JPG","text":"IMG_0250.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"IMG_0251.JPG","text":"IMG_0251.JPG","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"jingling.rar","text":"jingling.rar","parent":"Junk"},
            {"id":"Junk","text":"Junk","parent":"#"},
            {"id":"pics.rar","text":"pics.rar","parent":"Junk"}
        ];

    function shiftDoubles(double) {
      var sorted = mm.filter(function(element) {

        if (element.id != double) {
          return element;
        }

      })
      return sorted;
    }

document.write(JSON.stringify(shiftDoubles("Junk")));
```

Comment: But, for this I have to manually enter the ID's one by one. I want to clean the whole array without having to worry about the ID

Comment: Hence the *If the ID of the objects is always the same you can do this:* If you want that look at the other answer.

Comment: Isn't there any function that can do it? I'm assuming that the objects being values wont make any difference

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep: I can write something similar as that *Mykybo* did, but that's unnecessary considering the fact that his code does exactly what you need.